# Content Negotiation is not working in Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have following code to demonstrate content negotiation in web api. But it throws exception.

```
IEnumerable<Person> personList = _repository.GetAllPerson();

if (personList == null)
    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

IContentNegotiator negotiator = this.Configuration.Services.GetContentNegotiator();
ContentNegotiationResult result = negotiator.Negotiate(typeof(Person), this.Request, this.Configuration.Formatters);
if (result == null)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
    throw new HttpResponseException(response);
}

HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage()
{                
    Content = new ObjectContent<IEnumerable<Person>>(
        personList, // What we are serializing 
        result.Formatter, // The media formatter
        result.MediaType.MediaType // The MIME type
        )
};

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseMsg);
```

the exception is:

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.

Please give me a suggestion. and my WebApiConfig.cs code is:

```
// Web API configuration and services

//XML output
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;

//Json output
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;
json.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;
json.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;

// Remove the XML formatter
//config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is with the last line.

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseMsg);
```

Answer is:

```
return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new ObjectContent<IList<PersonModel>>(
                    personModelList, // What we are serializing 
                    result.Formatter, // The media formatter
                    result.MediaType.MediaType // The MIME type
                    ),
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

This is about serialization, not content negotiation.  I'm guessing you are querying a database and getting back `IQueryable` results from the repository using Entity Framework? A few steps to try:

Change this:

```
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
```

to this:

```
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Ignore;
```

You also may need to disable lazy loading in your EF configuration, depending on how `Person` is shaped:

```
public MyEntitiesContext() : base("name=MyEntitiesContext", "MyEntitiesContext")
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
}
```

Another option (and maybe better strategy for a non trivial solution is to return a different class (view model, dto, or even a projection) from the web api rather than returning your EF entity.